# "at" command keeps popping an alert

Tags: macos, permission, big-sur

"at" jobs keeps popping an alert asking if I want to
give terminal extra permissions.

[image]

I give it permissions, but
on the next "at" invocation it repeats the pestering,

how would I make it cease and desist?

Comment: Do you know what is asking for this permission? (If possible please post a screen shot).

Comment: I get shafted by settings judging from the icon. Judging from the message it's core macOS itself.

Comment: Does Terminal have Full Disk Access allowed in System Preferences?

Answer (score 1):

You have to provide "*Full Disk Access*" to `Terminal` to prevent this kind of alert:

1. Open **`System Preferences`** from **`Apple`** menu.
2. In **`System Preferences`** click on `Security & Privacy`.
3. In `Security & Privacy`, click on the ***Privacy*** tab.
4. Select *Full Disk Access* from the left sidebar.
5. Click on the **Lock** icon to make changes, and provide it an administrator user / password.
6. Click the **`+`** button (below the list of apps).
7. Add `Terminal` App (it can be found in *Applications > Utilities*).
8. Make sure that the *checkbox* next to `Terminal` is ticked.

[image: Screenshot of macOS System Preferences - Security & Privacy - Privacy dialog window]